# Threading and Object Lifetimes with ARC

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa, nsthread

As I understand ARC, without a strong reference to an object, it is fair game to be collected (since its reference count is 0).

If, in a method in class A, I do this:

```
ClassB* b = [[ClassB alloc] init];
[b doStuff];
```

And in doStuff, I do this:

```
NSThread* t = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(theThread) object:nil];
[t start];
```

The reference count of `b` appears to be 0 since it went out of scope after the method in class A finishes.  However, a thread is currently 'running' in ClassB and will need local resources.

What is the behavior here?  Or perhaps, what should the behavior here be to make sure that `b` stays around until the thread is all finished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation for `initWithTarget:selector:object:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-SW11) says that the thread takes ownership of (keeps a strong reference to) its target. The target will be released when the thread object is destroyed.

Be aware that this can cause a retain cycle, if the target also owns the `NSThread`.